# OpenRecentMenus in android 7

Tags: android, android-navigation

I try to use the following codes to show the android recent menu but it fails for android 7. (That works on android 4). Is that any additional permission required?
Anyone can help?

```
private void openRecentApps() {
    try {
        Class serviceManagerClass = Class
                .forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService",
                String.class);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(
                serviceManagerClass, "statusbar");
        Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder
                .getInterfaceDescriptor());
        Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0].getMethod(
                "asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null,
                new Object[] { retbinder });
        Method clearAll = statusBarClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
        clearAll.setAccessible(true);
        clearAll.invoke(statusBarObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

android 7 is something called android N, so perhaps it needs to be implemented as someone suggest, some kind of accessibility service.